# Installing and enabling multiple modules from backports

Tags: kernel-module, backport

I am modifying WLAN card driver modules from linux backports. Currently, I've modified `ath9k_htc` and `iwlwifi`.

Apparently, I remember that both dirvers have been working together when I have not modified dirvers at all. But I can't make both drivers work simultaneously after modifying drivers.

Here's a problem I have:

**1: install only `ath9k_htc`:**

```
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
sudo reboot
lsmod
```

There is no `iwlwifi` listed

**2: install only `iwlwifi`:**

```
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
sudo reboot
lsmod
```

There is no `ath9k*` listed

**3: install both (I am not sure if what I've done is on the right way):**

```
make defconfig-ath9k defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
sudo reboot
lsmod
```

Then, only one of two drivers are listed in `lsmod`.

Suppose `ath9k_htc` is working, then `iwlwifi` throws such messages in `dmesg`:

```
[   22.563631] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_start_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe
[   22.563637] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_start_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe (err -22)
[   22.563645] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_report_wowlan_wakeup
[   22.563647] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_report_wowlan_wakeup (err -22)
[   22.563657] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_chswitch_done
[   22.563660] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_chswitch_done (err -22)
[   22.563718] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_alloc_hw
[   22.563720] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_alloc_hw (err -22)
[   22.563801] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_find_sta
[   22.563803] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_find_sta (err -22)
[   22.563809] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_iter_keys
[   22.563811] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_iter_keys (err -22)
[   22.563852] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_enable_rssi_reports
[   22.563854] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_enable_rssi_reports (err -22)
[   22.563862] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_stop_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe
[   22.563865] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe (err -22)
[   22.563873] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_ave_rssi
[   22.563875] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_ave_rssi (err -22)
[   22.563992] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_resume_disconnect
[   22.563995] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_resume_disconnect (err -22)
[   22.564004] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim
[   22.564006] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim (err -22)
[   22.564021] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_request_smps
[   22.564023] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_request_smps (err -22)
[   22.564070] iwldvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_disable_rssi_reports
[   22.564072] iwldvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_disable_rssi_reports (err -22)
```

Vice versa for `ath9k_htc` when `iwlwifi` is working.

Could anyone give me an adivce to make both drivers work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is still relevant but try

```
make defconfig-wifi
make menuconfig // select all the drivers you want (Atheros, Intel, etc.)
make & make install
```

You will get all the drivers you selected installed.

Answer (score 0):

After module installation (as you mentioned).

Add the both modules `ath9k` and `iwlwifi` in `/etc/modules`. 
So they will be loaded at boot time.